# Vagrant: Clonar repositorio GitHub durante provisionamiento

Tags: git, github, vagrant

Estoy intentando clonar un repositorio **privado** alojado en GitHub durante el provisionamiento de un box Vagrant.

Mi `Vagrantfile` es el que sigue a continuación:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |shell|
    shell.env = {SSH_AUTH_SOCK:ENV['SSH_AUTH_SOCK']}
    shell.path = "bootstrap.sh"
  end
end
```

El script para provisionamiento:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
su - vagrant << EOF
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK

mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh -T git@github.com

git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
EOF
```

A pesar de haber configurado `ssh.forward_agent`, haber exportado `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` y adicionado los `known_hosts`, recibo los siguientes mensajes de error durante el provisionamiento:

```
default: # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-792c3f41
default: # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-792c3f41
default: # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-792c3f41
default: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
default: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
default: Cloning into '.'...
default: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
default: 
default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
default: and the repository exists.
```

Cuando accedo a la box via `vagrant ssh`, `ssh.forward_agent`  funciona correctamente reconociendo mis credenciales y clonando el repositorio. Pero no logro entender por qué no funciona durante el provisionamiento.

Alguna idea para resolver esto?

Comment: Esa es una buena pregunta, porque a mí me pasaba lo mismo y acabé desistiendo xD